# resume git download job interrupted by ctrl-z

Tags: ubuntu

I am using the command

```
sudo git clone git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
```

to download moodle. After partial downloading, it just halts without any valid reason. How can I suspend the job at such a stage and resume it later?

Comment: Are you asking how to suspend git so that it can be resumed later, or about how to continue a git clone that was interrupted?

Answer (score 0):

The Moodle Git repository is quite big it seems. You may want to clone it with

```
git clone --depth=1 git://git.moodle.org/moodle.git
```

unless you need all history.  Be aware that this still creates a local repository of 282 MB (a full clone uses 642 MB and the checking out of the `HEAD` branch takes some time and resources, which is why your command appears to be hanging).  Add `--branch=name` after `git clone` to clone a particular branch of the repository.

In general, a command can be suspended at the command prompt with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, and later resumed with the command `fg`.

However, when it comes to commands that uses a network connection, being suspended for a while may see the connection disappear due to various timeouts. The job may then fail upon resuming it.

Also note that you *never* have to check out a repository as the root user.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux system, you can send a `SIGSTOP` signal in order to pause a process. Than you can send a `SIGCONT` in order to resume the state of the process. Use the `kill` command to send the signal, and `ps -ATf | grep "git clone"` in order to filter the process